# Why is terraform erring with 'SignatureDoesNotMatch: Signature expired'?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, terraform

I started getting the following when running terraform commands:

```
$ terraform refresh
Error refreshing state: 1 error(s) occurred:

* SignatureDoesNotMatch: Signature expired: 20170226T035111Z is now earlier than 20170227T013047Z (20170227T014547Z - 15 min.)
        status code: 403, request id: 7626f995-fc8e-11e6-9b73-7990b2a1af41
```

What does it mean?  How to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

The AWS APIs use an authentication mechanism that involves the client creating a signature representing the request. This signature includes a timestamp of the time the request is being made, as a measure to reduce the risk of replay attacks.

The signature mechanism assumes that the client and server both have somewhat-accurate system clocks, such that the client's time is not more than 15 minutes divergent from the server's.

So it's important that any system where AWS APIs are used -- whether via Terraform or otherwise -- has a reasonably accurate system clock. Virtual machines often suffer from system clock drift for various reasons, so it's a good idea to run [`ntpd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntpd) on most virtual machines to prevent their system clocks from drifting too much.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out my virtual machine where terraform was installed was way out of sync with time.  Using the date command and a current time resolved the issue.

Comment: You should know that setting the date once isn't a good solution. You should install ntpd, and configure it properly so your system time stays consistent in the long term.

Comment: The affected RancherOS Vagrant (https://github.com/rancher/os-vagrant) has ntpd running.  I'll try to figure out how to make it work properly with  my VirtualBox and my physical machine going to sleep...

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu execute `sudo chronyd -q` to sync time